# Problems installing ubuntu on my notebook

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

I burned the ISO image file onto a cd, and restarted my laptop, the cd loads correctly and i get the start-up menu, when i select the "Install Ubuntu" option, my screen goes blank. Any suggestions..

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the safe graphics mode option?

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootParameters

Comment: tried it on virtual box, its working. I'm new to ubuntu, would like to know why this problem occured, and will changing the boot parameters change any features in the OS?